# Prolog - Operator in predicate

Tags: prolog, operators

Is it possible to include operators (like +, >, =, !=, >= etc.) in argument for a predicate (examples below are  just a demonstraition and do not have much use)?

```
test(A > B) :- A > B.
test(A >= B) :- A < B.
```

Seems to work, but:

```
test(A != B) := A > B.
test(A <> B) := A < B.
```

Does not - why is that? Why sometimes the operators can be included and sometimes not? How can I make `test(A != B) := A > B.` work?

I am working under sicstus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbols `!=`, `<>` and `:=` are not operators in Prolog. You need to make them operators, with the `op/3` directive. The operator declaration must be seen by Prolog before it parses your code.

The character sequence `!=` is not a token in Prolog, so you need to surround it with single quotes.

```
:- op(700, xfx, '!=').
:- op(700, xfx, <>).
:- op(1100, xfx, :=).

test(A '!=' B) := A > B.
test(A <> B) := A < B.
```

The above defines a predicate with two clauses. The clauses has no bodies, the name of the predicate is `:=` and its arity `2`. It is exactly the same as:

```
:=(test('!='(A,B)), >(A,B)).
:=(test(<>(A,B)), <(A,B)).
```