# what does <> mean in prolog?

Tags: prolog, turbo-prolog

example:

```
PREDICATES
nondeterm likes (symbol,symbol)

CLAUSES
likes (ali,football).
likes (ali,tenis).
likes (ahmad,tenis).
likes (ahmad,handball).
likes (samir,handball).
likes (samir,swimming).
likes (khaled,horseriding).

GOAL
%
likes (Person, G1), likes (Person,G2), G1<>G2.
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: [Prolog - Operator in predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534509/prolog-operator-in-predicate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that example, `<>` means "is not equal". The query:

```
likes(Person, G1),
likes(Person, G2),
G1 <> G2.
```

Is meant to find a `Person` that likes two things. Without the `<>`, `G1` and `G2` could be equal to each other and the query could find a `Person` that likes only one thing.

`<>` may be specific to Visual Prolog. In other Prolog environments you would use `\=` or `\==` instead.